# How to use Firebase retrieved data outside onDataChange functions like in Toolbar etc

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here I am adding the snippet where I am successfully retrieve data from firebase and use it as in my textview inside onDataChange() function but when I try to use it outside this function then it's not working and also I dont want to bring TOOLBAR inside onDataChange Function cause I have other places too where I need to use the data.

```
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserProfile userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
            //profileName.setText(userProfile.getName());


                pasteName = userProfile.getName();
                pasteEmail = userProfile.getEmail();
                testCase.setText(pasteName);//THIS IS WORKING


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(LoggedIn.this,"Problem Fetching Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain);
    toolbar.setTitle(pasteName);//NOT WORKING
```

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback. And as a quick fix, move the last two lines of code inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the request is async, so `pasteName = userProfile.getName();` is executed after the query finishes, so you have the info available.

> toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain);
>
> toolbar.setTitle(pasteName);//NOT WORKING

That won't work because that executes immediately after the query was executed, but it might have not finished.

Comment: Thanks.. But can it be rectified for the correct and desirable result ... ?

Comment: The correct way to do that is just as you did: put the code (or better, create a function) and call it from inside the onDataChange method. The key here is that the line with //NOT WORKING executes sync and the "pasteName" and "pasteEmail" variables have not been loaded yet (the request has not finished)